# Кастомизация ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

Во фрагменте есть ExoPlayer

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent"
    ads:show_timeout="0"
    ads:surface_type="none"
    app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_playback_control_view">

</com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView>
```

Кнопки я кастомизировал и указал в app:controller_layout_id, но вот если аудио содержит обложку, то оно отображается. Мне нужно чтобы обложки не отображались. Как сам плеер кастомизировать (чтобы не отображалась обложка аудио)?